# Asynchronous uploads across page loads

Tags: javascript, php, asynchronous, refresh

I am looking for a way to maintain file uploads across page changes. A Laravel and jQuery project I am working requires the uploading of multiple video files. The department's workflow is very tight, so the ability to fire an upload and move on would greatly enhance the site.

This is a new requirement, and I need some pointers to good solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "across page changes" ?

Comment: Start an upload and move to a new page on the same site.

Comment: popups would be the simplest option...

Comment: Dan, are you thinking something similar to T4NK3R's idea of opening the upload in a new window?

Answer (score 0):

So long as the `window` and `document` resources don't change you can keep uploading.

If you reload the page (like pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) all context and open resources are lost. You can not open a file resource in JavaScript without going through an explicit file selector.

If you need to reload you might be able to do some trickery with history and an iframe where the uploader sits in the parent frame (that never reloads) but that just gets really messy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe open the upload form in a new window - and let it sit till it's done, while the user moves on in the original window - that would also allow multiple (concurrent) uploads...